# SQLite DB not doing transactions when using PRAGMA foreign_keys = off

Tags: javascript, sqlite, angular6, nativescript, nativescript-angular

We have an nativescript-angular app that uses nativescript-sqlite to communicate with a local SQLite DB. The Following are issues we are facing:

ISSUE 1: 
There is a table with a composite primary key(Table A). There are few tables that use those primary keys as foreign keys(Table B,C,D). When attempting to delete rows from Table B,C,D I am getting a foreign key mismatch error.

ISSUE 2:
SQLite does not delete Columns from Tables. The work around is to create a new temp table, insert the data, delete old table, rename temp table. I have implemented like the code attached. The code runs fine and give no errors but when I check the DB the Column is still present.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
this.databaseService.getdbConnection().then(db => {
  db.execSQL(`
  PRAGMA foreign_keys=off;
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_table( 
     column_definition,
     ...
  );
  INSERT INTO new_table(column_list)
  SELECT column_list
  FROM table;

  DROP TABLE table;

  ALTER TABLE new_table RENAME TO table; 

  COMMIT;

  PRAGMA foreign_keys=on;
  `).then(id => {

  }, error => { 

  });
});
```

Issue1: allow deleting the rows from table that are using the foreign keys (TABLE B,C,D)

Issue2: The column from the table should be deleted

Comment: Does this `execSQL` function execute *all* statements in its argument or just the first one? Double check the documentation.

Comment: The code also shows nothing in the error action.  How are you determining whether or not the code is actually committed without error?  If there is an error, how are you properly rolling back the transaction?  Unless you show otherwise, I assume that the code allows the connection to terminate while possibly inside an uncommitted transaction with an unknown error.  In that case, the column would certainly not be deleted since the entire transaction would be discarded.

Comment: The question title and question details really don't match. The details do not describe any problem with transactions as implied in the title. Do you need to add more details or edit the title to match the actual problem? You should also submit two separate questions for each issue unless they are somehow related.  Add more explanation if needed, since to me they seem like completely separate issues.

Comment: When you get around to posing separate a separate questions, you definitely should post the DDL (i.e. CREATE TABLE statements) for the tables that you listed. It is not sufficient to simply say that they exist. We need to see the actual definition of the primary and foreign keys. Also show a sample DELETE statement that is failing. Even better would be to show example data of the primary record and the child record which is causing the error. Otherwise you will likely just receive guesses at what's causing the error.

Comment: @Shawn that was the issue the execSQL command did not take multiple queries. If you see fitting to post it as an answer I will vote it up and mark it. Thanks.

Comment: @CPerkins thank you for the input I will try to be more descriptive next time posting here

Comment: @FaizKhalid  I hope that my comments help.  However, the intention is that you **edit the current question and improve it** by filling in gap and clarifying confusing details mentioned in comments.  The comments are not mere suggestions for "next time".  If you do not edit the question and improve it, you are less likely to get a good answer.